# XSD Schema Validation Error : must not contain the '<' character

Tags: java, xml, xsd

***My XSD File :***

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="sample">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="synopsis"/>
            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="genre"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

***XML File :***

```
<asset 
synopsis="A romantic affair.<br><br>Contains one use of stronand moderate sex<br><br>Buy it" genre="Drama"/>
```

Java Code :

```
// javax.xml.validation.Validator;
validator.validate(new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlContent.getBytes(UTF_8))));
```

Getting the below error :

`java.lang.AssertionError: XML Validation Error :The value of attribute "synopsis" associated with an element type "asset" must not contain the '<' character.`

Any clues how to allows the `<` and `>` characters in the xml attributes values?

Answer (score 0):

Escape `<` as `&lt;` within XML attribute values.

Optionally, for symmetry, escape `>` as `&gt;` within XML attribute values.

See also [Simplified XML Escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46637835/290085).

Comment: No , I dont want to escape any values. Is ther any possible way to allow these charcters in the attribute values?

Comment: Not if you want your data to be XML.  The definition of XML itself precludes what you want.